# mutating state in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My reducer mutate the state, which i dont want, please help

**#Supplier Slice**

```
import { createSlice,createAsyncThunk,createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axios from 'axios'

export const getSupplierData = createAsyncThunk(
    'supplier/getSupplierData', async () => {
        const response = axios.get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/supplier/"
        );
        const data = await (await response).data
        return data
    })

const suppliersAdapter = createEntityAdapter({})


export const { selectAll: selectSuppliers, selectById: selectSupplierById} = suppliersAdapter.getSelectors(
    state => state.suppliers
)
export const saveSupplier = createAsyncThunk('supplier/saveSupplier',
    async supplier => {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/supplier/', supplier)
        const data = await response.data
        return data
    }
)


export const suppliersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'suppliers',
    initialState:suppliersAdapter.getInitialState({}),
    reducers: {
        newSupplier:(state,action)=>action.payload
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [getSupplierData.fulfilled]: suppliersAdapter.setAll,
        [saveSupplier.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>state.push
    }
})

export const { newSupplier } = suppliersSlice.actions

export default suppliersSlice.reducer
```

**#supplier**

```
const onSubmit=data=>dispatch(saveSupplier(data))
```

When i call this it replaced the list of supplier with the new data passed from the form
It mutates the state, which is not desireable

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `[saveSupplier.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>state.push` from your `extraReducers`. What you're doing now is trying to set the value to a function, which is why you'd also see a non-serializable error in your console with this code. If you just want to leave it as a placeholder and not update anything, just do `[saveSupplier.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {}`. Either way, I imagine what you actually want is `[saveSupplier.fulfilled]: suppliersAdapter.addOne` there?